# C# issue with oledb connection string for excel

Tags: c#, oledb

I receive a string like "c:\test\abc.xlsx" which indicates me the excel path. I have to depend on what i receive and cannot hard code it.  Now what how should i make sure the the single "\" is escaped and it becomes "\"

```
string **PATH** = "c:\test\abc.xlsx"
string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=**PATH**;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single "\" doesn't appear to be escaped properly.

Try: `string path = @"c:\test\abc.xlsx";`

The leading @ sign will escape it properly for you

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple:

```
String thePath = "c:\\test\\abc.xlsx"
String conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + thePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

Comment: Hey I am new to C# ; but if you see i should replace the single "\" to "\\" for the path, else the code gives an error, how do i do it.